# What is '~' sign annotate when we define pathPrefix in scala REST service?

Tags: scala, restful-architecture, spray, akka-http

```
pathPrefix("ball") {
pathEnd {
  complete("/ball")
} ~
  path(IntNumber) { int =>
    complete(if (int % 2 == 0) "even ball" else "odd ball")
  }
}
```

What is '~' sign indicates here

Comment: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.9/scala/http/routing-dsl/routes.html#composing-routes

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're referring to the `~` method on Spray/Akka-HTTP. What it does is chain two routes together:

```
/**
 * Returns a Route that chains two Routes. If the first Route rejects the request the second route is given a
 * chance to act upon the request.
 */
def ~(other: Route): Route = { ctx ⇒
  route {
    ctx.withRejectionHandling { rejections ⇒
      other(ctx.withRejectionsMapped(rejections ++ _))
    }
  }
```

In Spray, a `Route` is a type alias for a function taking in a `RequestContext` and returning `Unit`:

```
type Route = RequestContext ⇒ Unit
```

And in Akka-HTTP, it returns a `Future[RouteResult]`:

```
type Route = RequestContext => Future[RouteResult]
```